# Como fazer um print em VBA

Tags: vba, excel-vba

Eu tenho um excel cheio de informação

Mas quero separar a informação

Imaginando que tenho numa celula A-ABC-DEF

Como é que eu consigo que apareça o ABC através de uma formula no VBA

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Imprimir colunas alternadas vba excel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/273092/imprimir-colunas-alternadas-vba-excel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sugestão**

Dependendo da situação é melhor utilizar a fórmula abaixo do que criar em VBA:

`=EXT.TEXTO(C5;E5;F5)`

[image: COPIANDO PARTE DO TEXTO SEM VBA]

Comment: Entretanto consegui fazer, utilizei uma outra forma, mas obrigado pela sugestão, utilizei um pouco esse racioncinio

Comment: Se poder, favor marcar a resposta com a seta pra cima. Obrigado!

Comment: @Braga, favor ler [Como devemos formatar perguntas e respostas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1084/75104)

Comment: @braga ainda não tenho pontuação suficiente para isso.. Mas assim que tiver irei por

Comment: OK, obrigado pela atenção.